# Retrieve last row with specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have a table like:

| ID | Account | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4455 | 52 | 01-01-2022 |
| 2 | 4455 | 32 | 02-01-2022 |
| 3 | 4455 | 23 | 03-01-2022 |
| 4 | 4455 | 23 | 04-01-2022 |
| 5 | 6565 | 236 | 01-01-2022 |
| 6 | 6565 | 623 | 02-01-2022 |
| 7 | 6565 | 132 | 03-01-2022 |
| 8 | 2656 | 564 | 01-01-2022 |
| 9 | 2656 | 132 | 02-01-2022 |

We need to retrieve every last row of given `account_no`. We need output like:

| ID | Account | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4455 | 23 | 04-01-2022 |
| 7 | 6565 | 132 | 03-01-2022 |
| 10 | 2656 | 13 | 03-01-2022 |

Kindly suggest me a query to retrieve data like this in table of 2000 records.

Answer (score 0):

You want the last row of certain query. So you must be having an order by clause. Just reverse the ordering and use a limit clause with limit set to one row.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
order by your_reversed_orderby_clause
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT ID,Account,Amount,Date
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RN 
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE RN=1 
ORDER BY ID;
```

| ID | Account | Amount | Date | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4455 | 23 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 7 | 6565 | 132 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 9 | 2656 | 132 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 1 |

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f698817f3e4745117038bfc44295eca)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT max(ID) FROM table_name
  GROUP BY Acount
  ORDER BY Account
)
```